# Do I need to account for host machine's endianness when writing to my Buffer class?

Tags: c++, memory, byte, buffer, endianness

I'm writing a Buffer class which simply holds bytes in C++. It's got the usual read and write methods for various types; 16, 32 and 64 bit integers, floats and doubles. I'm using this primarily for in-memory loading/processing and file I/O, probably also some networking usage later on.

Instead of relying entirely on the host machine's endianness, the class has a built-in endianness switch, so all read and write methods will read/write the given values' underlying bytes to their destinations in the desired order.

My question is, should I be accounting for the endianness of the machine running this program while also observing the selected endianness mode of the buffer?

Example:

```
void Buffer::WriteInt32(int _int)
{
    bvec bytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_INT32; i++)
    {
        bytes.push_back
        (
            _int >> (m_Endianness == Endian::BIG ? ((SIZE_INT32 * 8) - ((i + 1) * 8)) : i * 8)
        );
    }

    m_Bytes.insert(std::end(m_Bytes), std::begin(bytes), std::end(bytes));
    m_Length += SIZE_INT32;
}
```

This example method works, and writes in big or little endian order based on the user's preference. However, I have a sneaking suspicion I should be checking the endianness of the machine running this code and writing the bytes directly without alteration if the endianness of the system and the buffer's settings match... is this what I should be doing? As I don't realistically have the option of testing on an opposite machine, I'm left confused as to how the scenario might play out.

Similarly, for reading:

```
bool Buffer::ReadInt32(int& dest, bool useOffset, size_t offset)
{
    int val = 0;
    size_t index = useOffset ? offset : m_ReadOffset;
    if (ReadableRemaining(index) < SIZE_INT32)
        return false;

    for (auto i = 0; i < SIZE_INT32; i++)
    {
        val <<= 8;
        val |= m_Bytes[m_Endianness == Endian::BIG ? F_VAL(index, i) : R_VAL(index, i, SIZE_INT32)];
    }

    dest = val;

    m_LastReadSize = SIZE_INT32;
    if (!useOffset)
        AdvanceReadOffset();

    return true;
}
```

The code stores the value retrieved from 4 bytes into the given integer destination; the order the bytes are observed in is based on the buffer's endianness setting. Again, all works great, but could the machine running this code reverse the output of **val**? Do I need to add code in here to swap things around based on the host machine?

Comment: Endianness is an issue when you need to share data between systems. Even then, the most effective way is to convert the data only when absolutely needed, like when saving/writing it, or when loading/reading it. Once it's in memory it should be in the hosts native format, with no more conversions needed at run-time.

Comment: Also note that endianness for floating-point types is not well-defined, if defined at all. And that there might be *different* formats for floating-point data depending on system. There's no requirement that the native host format adheres to strict IEEE754 format, there may be variants. Which makes it even harder to share such values. This is only one reason it's recommended to use text-based formats for sharing, and endianness is another.

Comment: This class will be used during the process of reading and writing binary data to/from disk that could very likely end up on or originate from opposite-endianness machines.

Comment: Is it you that decide the format of the files? Then decide *one* single endianness for the files. Let the reader and writer do any possible conversion needed when loading or saving the data. When in memory, it should be all in the native format.

Comment: And this is why things like serialization libraries like (protobuf, flatbuffers, maybe even nlohman json if speed isn't an issue) exist. You describe a data format in a small input language and it will generate code that does the right thing, even between languages!

Comment: Warning : not only Endianness, but also `sizeof(int)` is likely to be platform specific. So at least don't use `int` but `std::int32_t` (or `std::uint32_t`)

Comment: You might be interested in [the template classes I use for this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283494/75307).  The use of such classes helps ensure that your code is absolutely clear as to which quantities are native and which are protocol-endian.  As others have mentioned, the conversion only makes sense for fixed-width integer types (and unsigned only, prior to C++23).

Answer (score 0):

After mulling it over for awhile, I've answered my own question. I just had a haze of confusion preventing me from seeing things clearly at the time :)

Given that:

1. Big and little endian machines store their values in memory
   according to their designated layout;
2. My buffer class stores nothing but raw bytes in the order given to it, for later use in-memory and elsewhere;
3. Users of the class select the endianness of every value written
   to/read from the buffer individually, regardless of the machine's endianness;

**I obviously need to be observing the machine's endianness before determining if an order reversal is necessary for a given range of bytes for each operation**. If the machine order matches the desired operation order, no reversal is done; otherwise, it is.

I've also taken some of your suggestions into account:

- Switched over to using **std::int32_t**, **int64_t**, etc. to avoid surprises.
- I've already been checking the sizes of the various types during reads and writes with my own hardcoded 2/4/8 byte sizes, so the switch to fixed width types makes even more sense.
- The project now checks the implementation for the existence of IEEE-754 floating point conformance, and ***will not compile* without it**. That's a rule I'm happy to live with. As for the accuracy of reproduced values, different code will handle this in the way deemed most appropriate; things that need determinism most likely won't be relying on basic float -> bytes -> different machine -> float conversions.
- Project specific file formats are already designed to be little-endian across the board, but thanks for the suggestion there too.